# Не отображаются запросы на удаление, обновление и добавление в БД Access в Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, access

Здравствуйте. У меня есть БД, созданная в MS Access, в ней есть 5 запросов: 2 на выборку, а 3 остальных: добавление, удаление, обновление. Так вот когда связываешь эту БД с Visual Studio (добавить новый источник данных и т.д.), 3 последних запроса Visual Studio не видит, есть только на выборку. Почему? Мне нужно, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку открывалась форма, в которой уже будет выполненный запрос в DataGridView. Или что можно сделать? Ответьте пожалуйста.

Comment: То, что вы написали, это просто текст, по нему не понять ничего. Нужно что то такое, что можно воспроизвести. Например [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)